# Github-like username url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-routing

I have this route that let me build custom url for users like
/thisismyname, and it works fine. But when I look at the log there is
something I don't like...

When I hit /gregory this is what is happenning:
1. Going to public_profile#public # Good
2. hitting /assets and trying to find a user with asset token # Not good

I thought my constraints would avoid this but it doesn't seem like it...

```
class PublicProfileConstraint
  def self.matches?(request)
     !['assets', 'admin'].include?(request.session[:token])
  end
end

get "/:token" => "profiles#public", :as => :public_profile,
    :constraints => PublicProfileConstraint
```

Here is the log:

```
Started GET "/gregory" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-03-05 12:44:43 -0800
  Processing by ProfilesController#public as HTML
  Parameters: {"token"=>"gregory"}
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE
"users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE
"users"."token" = 'gregorymarcilhacy' LIMIT 1
Rendered profiles/_modal.haml (0.1ms)
....
Rendered profiles/show.haml within layouts/application (154.7ms)
Completed 200 OK in 431ms (Views: 174.0ms | ActiveRecord: 5.5ms)

... Redering js files ...

# I DONT WANT THIS
Started GET "/assets/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-03-05 12:44:45 -0800
Served asset  - 404 Not Found (10ms)
  Processing by ProfilesController#public as */*
  Parameters: {"token"=>"assets"}
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE
"users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE
"users"."token" = 'assets' LIMIT 1
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/
Completed 302 Found in 312ms

... Rendering images ...

# AND I DONT WANT THIS
Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-03-05 12:44:45 -0800
  Processing by LandingController#landing as */*
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE
"users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
Rendered landing/landing.haml within layouts/landing (0.8ms)
Completed 200 OK in 288ms (Views: 23.5ms | ActiveRecord: 2.2ms)
```

Comment: Could you say why you don't want these things and elaborate on what you are trying to do? if you do that, perhaps I can help.

Comment: I don't want this because /assets is the path to the asset pipeline. And in my case it hits my profile#public action and try to find a user with the 'assets' token.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are searching `request.session` for the token, but this will always fail as that's the session store rather than the request parameters. You probably want the equivalent of `params[:token]` in the constraint class. The [request object documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#the-request-object) indicates that `request.path_parameters[:token]` might contain the value you are looking for.